# regex skips the first match

Tags: android, regex

The regex 
`.*([0-9]{3}\\.[0-9]{2}).*`
finds one match in "some short sentence 111.01 ", but it failed to match the first occurrence "111.01" in "some short sentence 111.01 & 222.02 "
I tried the lazy quantifier `.*([0-9]{3}\\.[0-9]{2})?.*` or `.*([0-9]{3}\\.[0-9]{2}).*?`  for no avail. 
Please help, I need to get both occurrences, here is my code.

Thank you

```
Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile(".*([0-9]{3}\\.[0-9]{2}).*");
Matcher m = myPattern.matcher(mystring);
    while (m.find()) {
        String found = m.group(1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to remove ".*"s. Try this:

```
        String mystring = "some short sentence 111.01 & 222.02 ";
        Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{3}\\.[0-9]{2})");
        Matcher m = myPattern.matcher(mystring);
        while(m.find()) {
               System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
        }
```

output:

```
Found value: 111.01
Found value: 222.02
```

Comment: I thought with Android one has to use the leading and trailing .*

Comment: Did you try it on android? There is no different library used, same java class (java.util.regex.Pattern) is used on android as well: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

The leading and trailing ".*" cause you to match the entire string in one match.  All the lazy quantifier does in your case is controls you getting the first, not last, occurrence in the subject.

Comment: Self correction:  I am not familiar with the php regex processor, but apparently even if you match the entire string the first time, e.g.:  ".*(match_this).*" it will still resume at the capture group.  Just so you know, some regex processors won't do that, e.g. perl:
    perl -ne 'print "$1\n" while (/.*?(\d{3}\.\d{2}).*/g)' <<< "blah 111.01 && 222.02"
will match exactly once, whereas:
    perl -ne 'print "$&\n" while (/\d{3}\.\d{2}/g)' <<< "blah 111.01 && 222.02"
will match both.